# DLib c++ linking error on android studio gradle file

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I want to use dlib library in my android project which is written in c++.

I selected c++ language because it will support iOS also.

So I follow these steps:

- I created android ndk project and I included that dlib library
  directly in my c++ code folder.
- I import .h files and I generated a app gradle file in android studio
  project.

But when I  am getting library .h files errors, means internal .h files getting errors.

```
Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Error:Build command failed.

Error:org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException:
```

Comment: Could you put your app gradle configuration, to see how is your dlib file linked?

Comment: I didn't added anything in gradle file regarding this dlib, I just added this.h and .cpp files in my cpp folder where I wrote my c++ code.

Comment: So, how are you linking and cross-compiling your c++ sources? using android.mk? As far as I know you need to define your jni bridge to call Java->c++.

Comment: I have jni cpp file and i added dlib code in that jni bridge file.So when I am loading that jni bridge file it will load that cpp file right?

Comment: Actually, you create a library .so between your sources and jni bridgle, and later you load the library in the java code.  So, probably your linking problem comes from the crosscompilation of your sources and dlib files. I think you don't specify your ndk module in the gradle files.